# Custom UIBarButtonItem placed completely wrong in iOS 8 and 9

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to implement a custom `UIBarButtonItem`. I have subclassed it (for other reasons) and I'm having an issue where it's placed correctly in iOS 10 and 11, but completely misplaced in iOS 8 and 9.

This is what it looks like in iOS 10 and 11, and is correct:
[image: iOS 10]

This is what it looks like in iOS 8 and 9, and is completely wrong:
[image: iOS 9]

The button should display a kind of 'badge' if there are new features available, but I won't be getting into that now. Just don't answer with "You don't need to subclass/wrapperView, you can send customView in init", there are other reasons for this approach. I am simplifying the issue.

In the initialiser for my custom `UIBarButtonItem` I create one `UIButton` and a `UIView`, namely: `button` and `wrapperView`.

The `wrapperView` is a basic `UIView` which contains the `button`. The `button` is constrained to a certain width, and is constrained to fit in the `wrapperView`.
At the end of my custom initialiser, I set `self.customView = wrapperView`.
(The wrapperView is wrapping more than just the button, so setting button directly as customView is not an option)

When the custom `UIBarButtonItem` is finished initialising, it is added to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [myButton]`.

There is a lot of code to make it, but I'll provide what I can:

```
class MyBarButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem{
    let button:UIButton

    override init(){
        button = UIButton(type: custom)
        super.init()
        //Set image and add target for button
        let wrapperView = UIView()
        wrapperView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wrapperView.addSubview(button)
        //constrain button to 0pt from top/leading/bottom/trailing of wrapperView.
        //Also constrain button to 26pt width (as wide as my image)
        wrapperView.addConstraints([/*myConstraints*/])
        button.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        button.clipsToBounds = false
        wrapperView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.customView = wrapperView
        self.style = .plain
    }
}
```

There is a lot more code, but this is still happening when I comment them out. Any idea what's happening here?

As my custom `UIBarButtonItem` is simply a regular `UIBarButtonItem` with a simple `UIView` (with subviews and constraints inside) as `customView`, and then put in `rightBarButtonItems`, shouldn't it be easily displayed on the right side?.. Is this an issue due to my constraints?

**EDIT**

Seems like this is indeed a problem with my constraints. It seems to me like constraints are 'illegal' in `customView`.. As soon as I remove any constraints, the button is back to where it is supposed to be.. But I'm not sure if I'm completely comfortable without constraints..
But when I now run my code in iOS 10 or 11 it has again been completely moved.. Damnit!